# Are the API endpoints consistent between Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps On-Premises?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

As I work on a project that requires interaction with the Azure DevOps API, I'm curious to know if the interface for on-premise installations is the same as the one provided for the cloud-based services. Does the API functionality remain consistent across both deployment options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use REST API to interact with Azure DevOps. [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0) walks you through:

- The basic components of a REST API request/response pair.
- Overviews of creating and sending a REST request, and handling the response.

Most REST APIs are accessible through [client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0#client-libraries), which can be used to greatly simplify your client code. You can refer to [Get started with the REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops) to integrate your app with Azure DevOps using the REST APIs.

Most REST APIs work with both Services and Server, but some only support Services. It is recommended that you check the official documentations based on your specific needs.